# Adding HTML, JQuery and CSS to drupal7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a very new user of Drupal and want to add this menu to my website. It has the HTML code with a CSS file,  two .js files and a few images.

I want to embed this code in a block into my Responsinve blog themed Drupal7 site
I don't even know where to start or end.I tried drupal_add_js but I think I missed something somewhere and reading the forums has got me all the more confused.

In short I need to understand every small point of how and where to make changes to my site folders.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to put `drupal_add_js` into your template.php file?

Comment: Yes, I did try that but it didn't help me..Maybe I missed something somewhere.

Comment: @user3249245, try to follow steps from my answer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do add js is:

1. Locate your theme folder, usually `/themes/your_theme_name` or `/sites/all/themes/your_theme_name`
2. Look for `template.php` in it
3. Look for `your_theme_preprocess_html()` function - 'your_theme' might be, 'bartik' or 'garland' or your theme name, if not - change it (usually, it's the name of the folder)
4. add `drupal_add_js('path_to_js') to function
5. That's it, clear your cache in `Admin > Config > Perfomance` and check your code

oh, and to add menu block,

1. `Structure > Menu` and create new menu or use existant, add menu items
2. go to `Structure > Blocks`, find your menu in list and select region for it

**p.s.**
and, yep, it's not the only way to add js, here you can find at least [7 ways](http://wearepropeople.com/blog/7-ways-to-add-custom-js-and-css-to-a-page-in-drupal) to do it

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add your js & css in the template file. 
When you go into sites/all/themes/your_theme_name

Look for a file that ends with .info
Best practice is to add all of your custom .js & css files there.

All HTML changes will be done in the .tpl template files.

Hope this helps.